# Oracle SQL - Inserting a row is causing a pop-up box?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm inserting a few rows of data into a table, and one of them is causing an unusual result.  The code is

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_GROUPRISK 
(GROUP, RISKLEVEL) VALUES ('APIs & Intermediates','Low');
```

When I run this statement, I get a pop-up with the word Intermediates.  If I click the X on the pop up, the row is inserted as

```
APIs null
```

Rather than as

```
APIs & Intermediates
```

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: & needs to be escaped or use `SET DEFINE OFF` before executing query.  Oracle uses & to define/allow a user input at runtime

Comment: Long discussion of it here: https://community.oracle.com/thread/468604?tstart=0

Comment: @xQbert:to be precise: the Oracle **tools** use the `&` for runtime input. Not the Oracle database. If you use a different tool then SQL*Plus or SQL Developer then this does not happen.

Comment: yes, that is more precise.  It's the tools causing the issue, not the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ampersand character & needs to be escaped in a sql string.

You can replace it with the character code instead.

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_GROUPRISK 
(GROUP, RISKLEVEL) VALUES ('APIs  ' || chr(38) || ' Intermediates' ,'Low');
```

alternatively you can place the & before the first single quote

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_GROUPRISK 
(GROUP, RISKLEVEL) VALUES ('APIs &' || ' Intermediates','Low');
```

Comment: @jdjohnson920 Dont forget to upvote and mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

'&' is used for substitution variables, so when you write '&' Oracle asks for a value to use a a substitute; for example:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO TABLE_GROUPRISK
  2  ("GROUP", RISKLEVEL) VALUES ('APIs & Intermediates','Low');
Enter value for intermediates: XXX
old   2: ("GROUP", RISKLEVEL) VALUES ('APIs & Intermediates','Low')
new   2: ("GROUP", RISKLEVEL) VALUES ('APIs XXX','Low')

1 row created.
```

You can not simply escape it:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO TABLE_GROUPRISK
  2  ("GROUP", RISKLEVEL) VALUES ('APIs \& Intermediates','Low');
Enter value for intermediates: YYY
old   2: ("GROUP", RISKLEVEL) VALUES ('APIs \& Intermediates','Low')
new   2: ("GROUP", RISKLEVEL) VALUES ('APIs \YYY','Low')

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO TABLE_GROUPRISK
  2  ("GROUP", RISKLEVEL) VALUES (q'[APIs & Intermediates]','Low');
Enter value for intermediates: ZZZ
old   2: ("GROUP", RISKLEVEL) VALUES (q'[APIs & Intermediates]','Low')
new   2: ("GROUP", RISKLEVEL) VALUES (q'[APIs ZZZ]','Low')

1 row created.
```

You can decide to avoid substitution:

```
SQL> set define off
SQL> INSERT INTO TABLE_GROUPRISK
  2  ("GROUP", RISKLEVEL) VALUES ('APIs & Intermediates','Low');

1 row created.



SQL> select "GROUP" from table_grouprisk;

GROUP
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
APIs XXX
APIs \YYY
APIs ZZZ
APIs & Intermediates
```